# How to optimize this sql query on + 2 million rows

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Sql database with +2 million rows and growing fast. There aren't many columns, only `code, price, date and stationID`.

The aim is to get the latest price by code and stationID.
The query works well, but takes more than 10s.

Is there a way to optimize the query?

```
 $statement = $this->pdo->prepare(

        'WITH cte AS 
        (

        SELECT stationID AS ind, code, CAST(price AS DOUBLE ) AS price, date

        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
             PARTITION BY code, stationID
             ORDER BY date DESC
         ) AS latest

        FROM price
        )
        
        SELECT *
        FROM cte
        WHERE latest  = 1
        '
    );

    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Edit:
There is an index on the first column called 'id'. I don't know if this helps.

The database (InnoDB) look like this:

```
id primary - int
stationID - int
code - int
price - decimal(10,5)
date - datetime
```

Edit 2:

The result need to be grouped by stationID and each stationID need to show many line. One line for every code with latest date.
Like this:

```
22456:
      code:  1
      price: 3
      date:  2023-06-21

      code:  2
      price: 2
      date:  2023-06-21

      code:  3
      price: 5
      date:  2023-06-21

22457:
      code:  1
      price: 10
      date:  2023-06-21

      code:  2
      price: 1
      date:  2023-06-21

      code:  3
      price: 33
      date:  2023-06-21
```

The json output should be like this:

```
{"1000001":[{"code":1,"price":1.661,"date":"2023-06-06 12:46:32","latest":1},{"code":2,"price":1.867,"date":"2023-06-06 12:46:32","latest":1},{"code":3,"price":1.05,"date":"2023-06-06 12:46:32","latest":1},{"code":5,"price":1.818,"date":"2023-06-06 12:46:32","latest":1},{"code":6,"price":1.879,"date":"2023-06-06 12:46:32","latest":1}],"1000002":[{"code":1,"price":1.65,"date":"2023-06-03 08:53:26","latest":1},{"code":2,"price":1.868,"date":"2023-06-03 08:53:26","latest":1},{"code":6,"price":1.889,"date":"2023-06-03 08:53:27","latest":1}],…
```

Comment: Check for and add indexes.

Comment: You can optimize this question by removing all the database engine tags except for the one that you're actually using.

Comment: Secondly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql

Comment: For performance help, we need at a minimum: the full table and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: @brad an index consisting of all 4 columns?

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server? `AS DOUBLE` doesn't look right

Comment: I see that tag was arbitrarily left in by @Sammitch. What database product are you actually using?

Comment: @MartinSmith It's a innoDB table and i make request with php / pdo.

Comment: My bad, the syntax quirks seemed pretty definitively MSSQL to me.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not images or links) output of `show create table price;` and `select version();` and `explain WITH ...rest of your query`.  this is minimal information needed to accurately provide help with optimization questions.  the command line mysql client is the easiest way to get text output.

Comment: is code an id in a different table?  is stationID?  how many different codes, and stationIDs, and code/stationID combinations are there?

Comment: @ysth Everything is in the same table 'price'. id is auto incremental number, different from stationID. Each stationID can have 6 code, code 1, code 2... code 6. Please see my edit

Comment: "latest price by code and stationID" meaning "latest price for _a particular code and station"?  Or meaning "latest price for _every_ code and station"?

Comment: What is the relevance of JSON?

Comment: This is a "groupwise-max" problem; see that tag I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you cannot have two rows with the same datetime for the same `code, stationID` pair, using the window function is a bit like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

```
select p.stationID, p.code, p.price, p.date
from (
    select code, stationID, max(date) as max_date
    from price
    group by code, stationID
) max
join price p
    on max.code = p.code
   and max.stationID = p.stationID
   and max.max_date = p.date;
```

It requires the following index:

```
alter table price add index (code, stationID, date desc);
```

This query should take less than 1 ms, as the derived table can be built from the index, and then it is reading just the required rows from the table.

Alternatively, if you know that every `code, stationID` pair will have received an updated price within a specific time period (1 hr, 1 day, 1 week), then you could significantly reduce the work required by the window function by adding a where clause to it:

```
with cte as 
(
    select stationID as ind, code, price, date, row_number() over(partition by code, stationID order by date desc) as latest
    from price
    where date >= now() - interval 1 week
)
select * from cte where latest  = 1;
```

Comment: I think your first answer is very close to what I need. Your code works, but I only get one result per id (not stationID why ?). Result need to be grouped by stationID and each stationID need to show many line. One line per code with latest date. like code = 1, date = latest, price = 3... code = 2, date = latestn price = 2... one line per code

Comment: Please see my edit 2 for the result expected. I can't use your second solution since i don't know the timeframe

Comment: @hbdev the first answer will absolutely give one row per stationID/code combination (or more than one if there are duplicates with the max date).  you must be doing something wrong

Comment: @hbdev I am guessing you neglected to change the select list from `p.*` to `p.stationID, p.code, p.price, p.date`, as expected by your code, so it can group by `stationID`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user1191247 wow thanks a lot, it's woking very fast now and the result is exactly what i need ! Can you explain me the different part ? I guess the second select take the row with latest date (for each code or only 1 ?) but i don't understand the first select and why p.* give another result

Comment: @hbdev `p.*` meant the first column returned in the result set was `id`, which was then being used to create the groups (`PDO::FETCH_GROUP`). As each `id` is unique, each grouping contained only one record. The inner query is a basic `GROUP BY` to get the latest date for each `code, stationID` pair. The result of the inner query is then joined to the original table to get the price for each row returned. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @user1191247 with your explanation I understand now. It's both simple and ingenious. I would never have thought of doing it this way. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you need the following index for your query to perform well (you only need to do this once, as part of your database design).

```
CREATE INDEX IX ON price
  (code, stationID, date DESC, price)
```

The first two columns can be in either order.

Comment: I'm not an expert in sql, can you tell me where i should use INCLUDE. In my CTE or before ? If you can give me a full example it would be nice

Comment: See new edits. It's a separate command to create an index on a table

Comment: I get a syntax error when i try to use CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED or INCLUDE. If i try without these 3 option to create simple index, it works but performance are the same

Comment: Well you've now changed your question that you are using MySQL not SQL Server so the syntax is different. See edit

Comment: Sorry, as i have say, i'm not a expert with database. Now i have add a index on the 4 column but still very slow. It's a InnoDB base, maybe it's important to say

Comment: Did you make the third column `DESC`